# Tanaka stochastic differential equation and Kolmogorov equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, reference-request

Given Tanaka sde

$$dX_t=[a{\rm sign}(X_t)+b]dW_t$$

is there associated a diffusion process and so a Kolmogorov (Fokker-Planck) equation? What is this equation?

References answering the question are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not quite an SDE in the sense that the right-hand side does not depend on $X$, so you can write the explicit solution 
$$ 
X_t = X_0+\int\limits_0^t[a\sign W_s +b ]\mathrm dW_s.
$$
On the other hand, the Kolmogorov equation is defined only for Markov processes, I guess. I am not sure that the process $X$ is Markov.


Comment: @Ilya: Thank you. Indeed, it was difficult to identify the very nature of this process.

Comment: @ Jon : a remark as noted by Ilya, your sde is not Tanaka's sde, the right equation is $dX_t=sign(X_t)dW_t$. Best regards.

Comment: @The Bridge: There is such a big difference that I cannot see it and this is not the remark by Ilya at all. As you can note, if I take the two constants to be $a=1$ and $b=0$ you are back to Tanaka sde otherwise it is just the sum of a Tanaka plus a normal Wiener.

Comment: @TheBridge is right, naturally: sign(X) is not sign(W).

Comment: @Didier Piau: Thanks, I will fix this.

Comment: Your SDE will have a unique weak solution which is a one dimensional diffusion with speed measure $(a{\rm sgn}(x)+b)^{-2}dx$ (as long as ${\rm sgn}(0)$ is defined appropriately).

Comment: @George Lowther: Thanks, but the question is, does it exist a kind of diffusion equation also in this case?

Comment: @Jon: I don't understand what you mean, what does "exist a kind of diffusion equation" mean? Do you mean a backwards equation/Fokker-Planck equation. There does, but it's a little different from the backward equations you get with smooth diffusion coefficient, as you have to enforce continuity of the derivative at time 0.

Comment: I mean, at zero (not time 0).

Comment: @GeorgeLowther: You got it! It is a Fokker-Planck equation I would like to see and I was not able to read from standard literature. Please, put it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!